# Differentiability on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by $f(x)= x^2$ If $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ If not

I have that $f$ is continuous at $0$, but is It differentiable?
My guess is that no but i can't justify it

Comment: Try writing the limit only using the definition with the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is differentiable at $0$.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=0$$

because

$$\left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|\leq\left|\frac{h^2}{h}\right|=|h|\to0.$$